# EMR spark not honoring number of executor conf

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-ec2, amazon-emr, spark-submit

I'm using --num-executor with EMR spark-submit but the conf is not getting honored. The job runs with multiple executors even if I set it `--num-executor 1`. I tried it with different EC2 instance type and the number of executors it runs by default seems to vary by instance types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess dynamic allocation is active. You must inactive this parameter on spark configurations or send in spark-submit line like this:

```
spark-submit --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=false --class ...
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. It works in both cases:
1: `--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=false --num-executor 1`
2: `--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors=1`